# AWS SES emails are coming in Junk of Outlook Mail

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, outlook, amazon-ses

Sending some automated emails through SES inside the organisation but those are directly going to junk folder of Outlook mail. Could anyone suggest how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook junk email logic is a little tricky. Even if you add the sender to your safe list, or disable automatic filtering in "Junk E-mail Options" (i.e. only emails from blocked senders are sent to Junk email folder), Outlook could still flag some emails, even internal emails, as junk.

If completely disabling automatic filtering in Outlook is an option for you, you can update the following registry entry to "1".

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\outlook
DWORD: DisableAntiSpam
Value of 1 disables the junk filter, 0 enables it
```

**Note:** Version 16.0 is for when you are using Outlook 2016. It will be different if you're using a different version.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue.
1.) Verify your Domain (Enable DKIM & Custom MAIL FROM domain)
2.) Verify your Email.

I think it's Custom MAIL FROM domain. Now, I'm getting emails in my outlook inbox folder after enabling Custom MAIL FROM domain.